# Most efficient way to break up a dataframe using multiple DateTimeIndexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains prices for a security each minute over a long period of time.

I would like to extract a subset of the prices, 1 per day between certain hours.

Here is an example of brute-forcing it (using hourly for brevity):

```
dates  = pandas.date_range('20180101', '20180103', freq='H')
prices = pandas.DataFrame(index=dates, 
                          data=numpy.random.rand(len(dates)), 
                          columns=['price'])
```

I now have a `DateTimeIndex` for the hours within each day I want to extract:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,8)
end   = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,17)
day1  = pandas.date_range(start, end, freq='H')

start = datetime.datetime(2018,1,2,9)
end   = datetime.datetime(2018,1,2,13)
day2  = pandas.date_range(start, end, freq='H')

days = [ day1, day2 ]
```

I can then use `prices.index.isin` with each of my `DateTimeIndexes` to extract the relevant day's prices:

```
daily_prices = [ prices[prices.index.isin(d)] for d in days]
```

This works as expected:

```
daily_prices[0]
```

[image]

```
daily_prices[1]
```

[image]

The problem is that as the length of each selection `DateTimeIndex` increases, and the number of days I want to extract increases, my list-comprehension slows down to a crawl.

Since I know each selection `DateTimeIndex` is fully inclusive of the hours it encompasses, I tried using `loc` and the first and last element of each index in my list comprehension:

```
daily_prices = [ prices.loc[d[0]:d[-1]] for d in days]
```

Whilst a bit faster, it is still exceptionally slow when the number of days is very large

Is there a more efficient way to divide up a dataframe into begin and end time ranges like above?

Comment: I'd think you're wasting a lot of time subsetting `prices`, which is probably very large, a very large number of times. Since you need to specify separate times for every day, perhaps first `groupby` to get a DataFrame for each day and then mask those much smaller `DataFrames` accordingly. Alternatively, if you know you only have like 10-15 unique ranges (say 8am - 10 pm, 7am - 1 pm, 7am - 5 pm)... You could just subset that small number of times and then select the correct dates

Comment: @Alollz perhaps I should have mentioned this in the question, but what I'm aiming to do is expose this to a c++ library via pybind11. As such, I want to do all the data slicing using pandas, and then expose the underlying numpy data array to c++

Answer (score 0):

If the hours are consistent from day to day as it seems like they might be, you can just filter the index, which should be pretty fast:

```
In [5]: prices.loc[prices.index.hour.isin(range(8,18))]
Out[5]:
                        price
2018-01-01 08:00:00  0.638051
2018-01-01 09:00:00  0.059258
2018-01-01 10:00:00  0.869144
2018-01-01 11:00:00  0.443970
2018-01-01 12:00:00  0.725146
2018-01-01 13:00:00  0.309600
2018-01-01 14:00:00  0.520718
2018-01-01 15:00:00  0.976284
2018-01-01 16:00:00  0.973313
2018-01-01 17:00:00  0.158488
2018-01-02 08:00:00  0.053680
2018-01-02 09:00:00  0.280477
2018-01-02 10:00:00  0.802826
2018-01-02 11:00:00  0.379837
2018-01-02 12:00:00  0.247583
....
```

EDIT: To your comment, working directly on the index and then doing a single lookup at the end will still probably be fastest even if it's not always consistent from day to day. Single day frames at the end will be easy with a groupby.

For example:

```
df = prices.loc[[i for i in prices.index if (i.hour in range(8, 18) and i.day in range(1,10)) or (i.hour in range(2,4) and i.day in range(11,32))]] 
framelist = [frame for _, frame in df.groupby(df.index.date)]
```

will give you a list of dataframes with 1 day per list element, and will include 8:00-17:00 for the first 10 days each month and 2:00-3:00 for days 11-31.

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately they aren't. I'll update the question to reflect this fact

Comment: additionally I want to get back *multiple* dataframes, 1 per day